# Pip thinks I am using 2.7, only 3.4 installed

Tags: python, macos

```
File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2793, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 673, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 576, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.5.6
```

I am getting this error when using pip.

I have found a work-around by using pip3 instead, but I would like to fix whatever mess I have on my hands. Mac on 10.10.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using virtualenv or a virtual environment?

Comment: @PatrickBeeson no, standard default python environment. Oddly, I am getting errors in scrapy too now, I wonder if its related.

Comment: Clearly you did have 2.7 installed (possibly because MacOSX itself comes with it and requires it), or, where else do those `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/...` paths come from?  `easy_install pip` might properly switch you to the 3.4-connected version (if your `easy_install` is...:-).

Comment: @AlexMartelli I agree. I went ahead and deleted all references to 2.7 in my path in hopes that would fix it (it didn't).

Comment: @AlexMartelli This is the result of easy_install pip Searching for pip
Best match: pip 1.5.6
Processing pip-1.5.6-py3.4.egg
pip 1.5.6 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing pip3.4 script to /Users/danielternyak/anaconda/bin
Installing pip script to /Users/danielternyak/anaconda/bin
Installing pip3 script to /Users/danielternyak/anaconda/bin

Using /Users/danielternyak/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py3.4.egg
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip

Comment: @user3839821 OS X has Python 2.7 installed and use it for default python interpreter. So I don't think you should just brutly remove it because it may cause some other issue.

Comment: @skyline75489 it was only the PATH I removed, so it should be fine.

Comment: Why you don't simply use `pip3`, which, I think, exist for Python 3... What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by home brewing python and python3 again.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the alias for python3 in your `.bashrc` file:

`alias python=python3`